# Plot multiple figures in the same subplot location [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I need to plot 2 different figures in the same subplot location. This is what I'm trying:

```
T = 0.25;
step = T/500;
t = 0:step:0.25;
phi=2*pi*t;
phi2=phi.*phi;
y=phi.*(1-(phi2/6));

tt=0:step:1-step;
yy=[y fliplr(y(2:500)) -y -fliplr(y(2:500))];

%Next 5 lines plot a sine wave with frequency and period of 1 and a sample
%rate of 2000 samples per second
f= 1;
step2 = f/2000;
t2=0:step2:1;
x=sin(2*pi*f*t2);

figure;
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(yy, 'b')
hold on;
plot(t2,x, 'r')
```

Notice how the "hold on" is keeping the blue graph but not plotting the last line of the code. If you move the "hold on" to the line after the 2nd plot, it shows the red plot (second plot) but not the first one. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is plotting everything. The red line is being plotted between x = 0 to 1 and the blue line is between x = 1 to 2000. This is because the x limits aren't specified in the blue plot so MATLAB assumes unit spacing. Try changing the first plot to `plot(tt, yy, 'b')`

Comment: Thanks it worked!